# Python 3.6: 'c' argument looks like a single numeric RGB or RGBA sequence

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, logistic-regression

While running below code from Machine Learning A-Z Course, getting the warning.

```
# Logistic Regression

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Social_Network_Ads.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, [2, 3]].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values

X = X.astype(float)
y = y.astype(float)

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)

# Fitting Logistic Regression to the Training set
#lbfgs = Limited-memory BFGS  It is a popular algorithm for parameter estimation in machine learning.
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0, solver='lbfgs') 
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

# Visualising the Training set results
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Logistic Regression (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Estimated Salary')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Full Error:

```
'c' argument looks like a single numeric RGB or RGBA sequence, which should be avoided as value-mapping will have precedence in case its length matches with 'x' & 'y'.  Please use a 2-D array with a single row if you really want to specify the same RGB or RGBA value for all points.
```

The issue is in below code:

```
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
```

However, not able to fix it. Any help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55109716/c-argument-looks-like-a-single-numeric-rgb-or-rgba-sequence

Comment: @furcifer its not exactly fixing the issue. The dots are going which is representing the dataset.

Comment: can you give the link to the dataset? or upload it somewhere?

Comment: added to my github -  https://github.com/bansalrishi/MLData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just seeing an warning, which should not be a problem. The following code runs without any error in 3.2.1

Check your matplotlib version.

```
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.__version__)
```

```
# Logistic Regression

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.axes._axes import _log as matplotlib_axes_logger
matplotlib_axes_logger.setLevel('ERROR')

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Social_Network_Ads.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, [2, 3]].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values

X = X.astype(float)
y = y.astype(float)

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)

# Fitting Logistic Regression to the Training set
#lbfgs = Limited-memory BFGS  It is a popular algorithm for parameter estimation in machine learning.
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0, solver='lbfgs') 
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

# Visualising the Training set results
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Logistic Regression (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Estimated Salary')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Just don't use ListedColormap, from version 3 you're supposed to pass the color as a string for each scatter point.

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Social_Network_Ads.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, [2, 3]].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values

X = X.astype(float)
y = y.astype(float)

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)

# Fitting Logistic Regression to the Training set
#lbfgs = Limited-memory BFGS  It is a popular algorithm for parameter estimation in machine learning.
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0, solver='lbfgs') 
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

# Visualising the Training set results
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ['red', 'green'][i], label = j)
plt.title('Logistic Regression (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Estimated Salary')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This shouldn't give any warnings.

Comment: oh sorry, yes warning, can code be corrected to avoid the warning?

Comment: suppressing the warning is not good, i already found that from matplotlib.axes._axes import _log as matplotlib_axes_logger
matplotlib_axes_logger.setLevel('ERROR').

Comment: Are you getting any unexpected results?

Comment: I am getting the correct result. But definetely want to fix this warning without work around. Want my code to be clean. Thanks for your help this far. Thumbs up for this. If you can provide solution to fix it, that will be great.

Comment: can you check the updated answer? Just dont use ListedColormap, from version 3 you can just pass a string.

Answer (score 0):

my case is using lag_plot() function

Solved it lilke this

```
lag_plot(np.log(data['numeric_column']), c = ['blue'][0])
```